# Ways to hide/show many items in a TableView

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I have a view controller that calculates land taxes for the Canadian provinces. Each one of these had different inputs, so the tableview that holds then ends up with three dozen fields.

I've seen code here that uses `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` to show/hide sections, and perhaps that is what I'm looking for. However, I find this practically impossible to work with in IB, the table extends way past the end of the display. Is there some way to deal with this?

Or perhaps I should use multiple tableviews stacked in IB and hide/show them as a whole?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to hide an entire section in a tableView is to return 0 in the tableViewControllers `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: But then don't I need to know the number of rows that there are when it isn't hidden? I could put these in, but is there an easier way?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz where are the number of rows coming from currently?  Without implementing this delegate method, a tableView assumes you want 0 in every section.

Comment: Uhhh, well this methods is not currently implemented in the VC. In fact, I think this is the first time I've ever implemented it. I assume it gets it from IB somehow?

Comment: Oh this isn't going to work anyway, there's multiple sections per form, I just realized that.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Interface Builder is for setting up your interface as well as some template cells.  Without some class in your app implementing the proper delegate and dataSource methods, your tableView can't display anything.

Comment: There's no data in these tables, in the common sense. The cells contain text fields that are individually wired to properties in the VC.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz then you're using UITableView wrong.  It's supposed to supply cells in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: with the text populated based on the data you have.  You should look at the Xcode "Master Detail" template and try and mimic what they're doing in there.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz if you wired controls to property it means your table is static, if you want to modify your tableView cells should be dynamic, it will make your life easier